# Dual collation in database, is it possible?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Has anyone got a work around for the situation where we get Russion, Chinese and English names with customer data and the non-English names end up as ‘??????’

If I set the coalition to e.g. Asian characters, will the English names end up with ‘??????’

I have thought of creating a staging table with the coalition set for non English characters and giving the customer entries an id number and then loading the id number as the name.  I would create a reference table to hold the non English names i.e. so we refer back to the original entries.

The simple question, for the moment, is can you use two different coalitions in a database.

Thanks for your input.

Cheers

C

Comment: Are you using nvarchar as datatype?

Comment: No were are not using the nvarchar.  From the responses I am going to set all personal and address columns to nvarchar then reload the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The collation only impacts the sorting and filtering of the data, not how it is stored if you use the proper data type. The sorting requires correct collation because that is how SQL server will know what comes first - `u` or `ū` etc.

What determines the storage is the data type - if you use `nvarchar` instead of `varchar` (and `ntext` vs `text`) then both Asian characters and Latin characters can coexist in the same column.

Comment: From the responses I am going to set all personal and address columns to nvarchar then reload the data.

The nvarchar should be able to hold the differnt name formats.  I just hope they dont start asking for translations.

Thanks for your input.  I think I have enough to get going with.

Cheers

C

Answer (score 0):

What collation are you using? All languages you mentioned can be represented using single collation, **UTF-8** maps all needed characters, and in fact, should be the collation of choice to facilitate working with this strings afterwards.

Comment: Also, already mentioned by others - SQL Server doesn't work well with UTF-8 in varchar columns, N-types (nvarchar/ntext) should be used instead: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx